# (General) Number of Constants in the Solution of ODE & PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

**Case I: ODE**

Is it true that the number of the constants in the general solution equals to the highset order of a derivative in the equation. If not, then there a rule about it.

**Case II: PDE**

Is there a similar rule for the number of constants in the solution. What has this to do with the boundary conditions.

Is there a book that handles all of that rigorously ?

Comment: In case of PDE one have to consider arbitrary functions instead of arbitrary constants. In the general solution of a first order linear PDE there is one arbitrary function.  In the general solution of a second order linear PDE they are two arbitrary functions. Etc.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but could you please mention a book that adresses this point fairly enough, i.e. rigorously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ODE

Yes, for the "regular" ones, that is, for those satisfying the local Lipschitz condition or some more exotic condition forcing uniqueness of local solutions. Then the nature of an Initial-Value Problem enforces the number of integration constants to be equal to the dimension of the state vector. For scalar ODE this is indeed also the order of the highest derivative.

#### PDE

The equivalent of initial conditions are values along some curve or other surface bounding the integration area. As function the number of independent parameters is infinite, even just taking local variations into account. The existence and uniqueness of solutions can depend on the shape of the boundary. The nature of the PDE can couple distant parts of the boundary, meaning that the values on these parts are not independent. It is not at all guaranteed that a solution exists on a strip of uniform width around the boundary.